# Is there a way to make dropdown checkbox with django-filter and location foreignkey for City from cities-light

Tags: python, django, django-filter

**I create a dropdown list checkbox with django-filter that I managed to
create for some fields with a choice option, but I can not retrieve
the database information for city-light cities . When put city for
choice value, I get this error :**

*

> TypeError at / 'City' object is not iterable

**this section work fine:**

```
        CITY_CHOICES = (
            ('city1','city1'),
            ('city2','city2'),
        )

        class PostFilter(filters.FilterSet):
            location = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(field_name='location', choices=CITY_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
            class Meta:
                model = Post
                fields = ['location']
```

**this problem section:**

```
from cities_light.models import City

class PostFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    location = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(field_name='location', choices=City, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['location']
```

I expect the same results for my city choices. How can i proceed on doing that

Comment: AFAIK, choices should be iterable, so you should change `choices=City` to `choices=CITY_CHOICES` or smth similar.

Comment: i want to retrieve city from city light in other word, my database like 30000 city

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#modelchoicefilter-and-modelmultiplechoicefilter-arguments) instead because you are using `City` which is a model. Like this:

```
class PostFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    location = filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=City.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['location']
```

Comment: thanks ruddra it work but it give me all the city at once when i click the dropdown it's not beautiful do you have a suggestion